# Уменьшение высоты блока CSS

Tags: html, css

Каким свойством можно уменьшить высоту блока на несколько пикселей? А то у меня такая структура: шапка блока, потом контент блока, потом футер блока, но футер с тенью внизу, и получается что тень обромляется обводкой слева и справа - не красиво, фиксированую высоту не хочется ставить... Подскажите пож-та

Comment: может margin применить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если футер внутри блока, попробуйте указать отрицательный `margin-bottom` для футера.

Это поднимет границу "футеросодержащего" блока на указанное количество пикселей.

Comment: Да, да, совсем про это забыл, сколько таким выкручивался раз, а сейчас прям их головы вылетело, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Высота свойство - height:
Ширина - width: